# PHP : parsing questions then getting the keywords

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I need to parse a question and then get the keywords and store them inside the database.

Example:

What is a void function?

I can already take out the stop words what, is, and a and store void and function inside the database. But I don't know how I'm gonna add void function inside the database.

Group of words like:
void function, declare arrays, split a string

Since I need to link tbl_dictionary which contains the parsed keywords to tbl_questions which contains the complete unparsed sentences.

When parsed, it should look like this:

sentence: What is a void function

```
[0] => What
[1] => is
[2] => a
[3] => void function
```

I've already done this:

```
[0] => What
[1] => is
[2] => a
[3] => void 
[4] => function
```

And I need to do the first one. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought:

You've got your initial array from the question.

Iterate through and remove the stop words.

Iterate again and enter each individual keyword into the dictionary, relating to the original question but then also implode the remaining words `implode(" ", $keywords_array)` to create the phrase and then insert that into the DB

Comment: I've already done the stopwords, I'll try the implode later. But my dictionary has to be dynamic. I can't enter the individual keywords manually, they have to come from the sentences inputted from the user homepage.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, all you are asking is how to insert the information into the database? What database are you using? Here is the MySQL syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dictionary (words) VALUES ("$keyword");
```

If I didn't answer your question, could you please clarify exactly what you need?

Comment: This isn't a MySQL-specific question, it's about grouping words, ie. "void function" is added as it is and no "void" or "function" is added to the table.

Comment: I do need to insert the information into the database and I can already do that. I just need to be able to combine words and insert them together since I need the keywords and phrases.

Comment: @vtorhonen, you're right on the part of grouping words "void function" and adding it. But I still need to add the separate words void and function as well. So there's going to be a "void, void function, and function" inside my tbl_dictionary

Comment: @johanahChua, alright. Are the keywords always in groups of two words? You gave two examples, "void function" and "declare arrays". How about creating a list of words that require another word before it, such as "function" or "arrays"? When you've added all the single keywords you can check if any of those exist on the string, ie. "function" or "arrays", and add it with the preceding word (or preceding words) to the database.

Comment: I've got a list of stop words that should be ignored in the search and a dynamic tbl_dictionary which adds the words that should be stored but it can only store 1 word not two or three words. The words on my tbl_dictionary doesn't duplicate, I've already prevented that.